# Receiving http status code 406

Tags: 8, routes

I have created a custom module in Drupal 8 and added the routing table to mymodule.routing.yml. Whenever I am trying to hit a particular path, I am receiving the HTTP response "406 (406 Not Acceptable)."

What is causing this?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about code the OP is not showing in the question.

Answer (score 3):

You need to return a Response object or a render array from a controller.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer either use #markup as key e.g

$element['#markup'] = "hello world";

2nd option :

$content = array();
    $content['fruits'] = 'Apple';
    $content['vegetable'] = 'Onion';
    $content['message'] = "Hello every one this First template of Drupal 8 ";

```
 return array(
   '#theme' => 'hello_show',
   '#content' => $content,
 );
```